# Validating a value using a generic validator

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

I have a class implementation that inherits from  `AbstractValidator<T>`

to keep things simple: Assume I have

```
public class Users{

[Required]
public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

what I woul like to do is to invoke

`RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();`

but the properties will be know at runtime so I would like to do this with reflection and expression trees..

I'm failing to invoke RuleFor method, below is my implementation and the commented parts are things I've tried.. any help is much appreciated.

```
GenValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> 
{
   // constructor etc..

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ValidateValueAsync(T model, string propertyName) 
        {
            try
            {
                var loType = model.GetType();
                var property = loType.GetProperty(propertyName);
                var param = Expression.Parameter(loType);
                var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, property);
                var lambdaExpressionType = typeof(Expression);
            
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(model.GetType(), typeof(object)), propertyExpression, param);
    
    
                var lambdaMethod = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Lambda", new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Expression), typeof(ParameterExpression[]) });
                var lambda2 = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(loType, typeof(object)).Invoke(null, new object[] { propertyExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { param } });
                var compileMethod = lambda.GetType().GetMethod("Compile");
                var func = compileMethod.Invoke(lambda2, null);
                var ruleForMethod = typeof(AbstractValidator<T>).GetMethod("RuleFor");
                var genericRuleForMethod = ruleForMethod.MakeGenericMethod(loType);
                genericRuleForMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { func });
    
                //RuleFor<object>(lambda).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The property is required.");
                //RuleFor(lambda.Compile()).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The property is required.");
    
    
    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
            }
            //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, param);
            //RuleFor(lambda).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The property is required.");
    
            var valContext = ValidationContext<T>.CreateWithOptions(model, x => x.IncludeProperties(_propertyName));
    
            var result = await ValidateAsync(valContext);
    
            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                return Array.Empty<string>();
            }
            return result.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class MyValidator
{
public MyValidator(string propertyname)
{
   // this is how you call using fluentvalidation but it's hardcoded.
   RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();

  // I do know want to hard code.
  //I want to do some magical stuff at this point 
  //and invoke the RuleFor method, I only have propertyname as a 
  //string, type of model and model at this point
   
  }
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
private void GenericRuleFor(T Model, string propertyName)
{
    var property = Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(Model.GetType());
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, property);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(Model.GetType(), property.PropertyType), propertyExpression, param);

    var abstractValidatorType = typeof(AbstractValidator<>).MakeGenericType(Model.GetType());
    var ruleForMethod = abstractValidatorType.GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "RuleFor" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
    var genericRuleForMethod = ruleForMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
    genericRuleForMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { lambda });
}
```

this is the modified version of my code which still does not work..
it throws an exception when I invoke genericRuleForMethod
telling me that **object type does not match Target type**

Comment: It seems you are trying to reinvent the wheel. There is already a library that does this. It is named `FluentValidation`

Comment: @Eldar: OP is already using FluentValidation. The question is about how to create rules without knowing what the properties will be until run time.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, please check again my updated question

Comment: Well, at first sight `var genericRuleForMethod = ruleForMethod.MakeGenericMethod(loType);` part is problematic. `RuleFor` method accepts a type parameter for the property, not the class itself. So it should be `ruleForMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);`

Comment: you are right, I've done some modification in my code, but still get an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working version of your `GenericRuleFor` is below. The main difference seems like you are trying to get the `RuleFor` method from the `typeof(AbstractValidator<>)` I just get it from the `this.GetType()`

```
    private void GenericRuleFor(string propertyName)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, property);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<, >).MakeGenericType(type, property.PropertyType), propertyExpression, param);
        var thisType = this.GetType();
        var ruleForMethod = thisType.GetMethod("RuleFor", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var genericRuleForMethod = ruleForMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
        // result is used by extension method
        var result = genericRuleForMethod.Invoke(this, new object[]{lambda});
        //NotEmpty method is an Extension metot which is contained by DefaultValidatorExtensions
        var extensionsType = typeof(DefaultValidatorExtensions);
        var notEmptyMethod = extensionsType.GetMethod("NotEmpty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(type, property.PropertyType);
        notEmptyMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]{result});
    }
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KXiyjm)

Comment: you are right, your code also saved me some time implementing the NotEmpty method. Thx